# How to use sapply to perform a linear regression on a dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, linear-regression, sapply

I am trying to simplify my code using sapply to run a function that performs a linear regression, plot and saves the image as a .pdf on all columns of a dataset that I imported as a .csv. Basically I have one column that contains numbers and I want to run a linear regression of all the other columns against this first column. Here's my code so far:

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read_csv("~/Desktop/tertileandvolume.csv", col_name = TRUE)
data <- na.omit(data)

run_all <- function(x){
    lm(data[,1] ~ x)
    summary(lm(data[,1] ~ x))
    ggplot(data, aes(x=names(data)[1], y=names(data)[x])) +
    geom_point(shape=1) + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE) + ggtitle("x") + labs(x=names(data)[1],y=names(data)[x])
    ggsave(path="~/Desktop/")
}

sapply(data, 2, run_all)
```

Also how can I use the column names to generate the axis labels for the plot? and then save it in ggsave using the same labels? I'm not very familiar with using sapply or the syntax I would need to use to make this work.

Comment: did you try `lapply(data[,-1], run_all)` ? the `-1` is to prevent your response variable to be used against itself. not sure what do you mean with `y=names(data)[x]` though.

Comment: I want to use the column names as the axis labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sapply does not have three arguments - you confuse it with apply. In any case, here you shouldn't use (s)apply but just a for loop:

```
for (col_name in names(data)[,-1]) run_all (data[,col_name])
```

If you want to be able to know the column name, just pass that instead of the whole column:

```
for (col_name in names(data)[-1]) run_all (col_name)

run_all <- function(col_name){
  x <- data[, col_name]
  l <- lm (data[,1] ~ x) # please note the rest of your code has more error!!
  summary (l)
  # gg <-ggplot ... #!!
  # etc
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `lapply(names(data)[-1], run_all)`
I copy and paste below your function, haven't try it yet because I don't have your dataset (I commented some changes):

```
run_all <- function(x, data){
    lm1 <- lm(data[,1] ~ data[,x]) # save the results
    summary(lm1)                   # so you don't have to do it here again
    ggplot(data, aes(x=names(data)[1], y=x)) +
           geom_point(shape=1) + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE) + 
           ggtitle("x") + labs(x=names(data)[1],y=x)
    ggsave(path=paste0("~/Desktop/",x))  # just to prevent the same filename
}

lapply(names(data)[-1], run_all, data)
```